# What's the default value of BlendEquation?

Tags: webgl

I'm reading source code of a WebGL app and found it doesn't use [`blendEquation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/blendEquation). But it has enabled `BLEND` and set [`blendFunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/blendFunc). And blending is working.

Does `blendEquation` have a default setting or value? What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See original OpenGL ES 2.0 [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf) or [reference pages](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/) it is clearly says that

> Initially, both the RGB blend equation and the alpha blend equation
>   are set to GL_FUNC_ADD.

Comment: FYI, the man pages are NOT OpenGL document, they are man pages. The real docs are the spec. The man pages have been known to be wrong quite often. Furthermore, the question is about WebGL, the page you linked to is OpenGL, WebGL is not based on OpenGL, it's based on OpenGL ES 2.0, [different spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf), [different man pages](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/)